# Is an old edition of Cinder Wall able to attack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The most recent iteration of [Cinder Wall](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cinder%20Wall) has the creature type "Wall" and has Defender. However, the Weatherlight print of this card stood by the old rules where Wall creatures couldn't attack, so it doesn't have the Defender keyword.

If I use a Weatherlight edition of this card, can it attack, or does the fact that its errata gave it Defender mean that older prints would also have it even if they do not say so?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No; Oracle is the authorative source of card wordings.**

From the Comprehensive Rulebook:

> 108.1. Use the Oracle™ card reference when determining a card’s wording. A card’s Oracle text can be found using the Gatherer card database at Gatherer.Wizards.com.

The official text on all versions of [Cinder Wall](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cinder%20Wall) is:

> Defender 
> When Cinder Wall blocks, destroy it at end of combat.

"Wall" specifically is mentioned in the Glossary:

> Wall

> A creature type with no particular rules meaning. Older cards with the Wall creature type but without defender had an unwritten ability that precluded them from attacking. Those cards have received errata in the Oracle card reference to have defender. Some older cards that referenced the Wall creature type have also received errata. See Defender.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't really matter what is printed on the card, since according to the rules:

> **108.1**. Use the Oracle™ card reference when determining a card’s wording. A card’s Oracle text can be found using the Gatherer card database at Gatherer.Wizards.com.

The Oracle text for [Cinder Wall](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cinder%20Wall) says:

> 

Defender

> When Cinder Wall blocks, destroy it at end of combat.

Answer (score 0):

> 108.1. Use the Oracle™ card reference when determining a card’s wording. A card’s Oracle text can be found using the Gatherer card database at Gatherer.Wizards.com.

All copies of a card, regardless of set or source, have identical rules regarding how they function in game. There are special situations where a card cannot be used as a normal card without some special conditions(the only ones that comes to mind are oversized cards like some commanders, and the slightly differently shaped cards of Alpha set.), but this is due to the cards being visually different from the back and therefore identifiable.

Besides this, there is no difference in game between using different sets versions of a card.